# BeginInvoke using a Function?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, asynchronous

This sub works fine:

```
Private Sub UpdateInfo(ByVal text As String, ByVal timeStamp As DateTime)
    If Me.lstStatus.Dispatcher.Thread Is System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread Then
        ' Do stuff with 
    Else
        Me.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send, New Action(Of String, DateTime)(AddressOf UpdateInfo), text, timeStamp)
    End If
End Sub
```

But this function doesn't:

```
Private Function UpdateInfo(ByVal text As String, ByVal timeStamp As DateTime) As ListItem
    If Me.lstStatus.Dispatcher.Thread Is System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread Then
        Dim l As New ListItem
        ' Do stuff with 
        Return l
    Else
        Me.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send, New Action(Of String, DateTime)(AddressOf UpdateInfo), text, timeStamp)
        ' Above line doesn't return anything??
    End If
End Function
```

How do I return my listitem in above function?

Thanks!!!!!

:)
Mojo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() is a fire-and-forget method, the delegate target runs at some later time on the UI thread.  That's not good enough in your case, you need to wait until the target runs so you can get the return value.  Use the Invoke() method instead:

```
 Return DirectCast(Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(..), ListItem)
```

And use Func instead of Action.  Or AddressOf, the more 'natural' VB.NET way.

Comment: What can I say?? You guys are GREAT! Damn you take away lots of frustrations. Just wanted to let you know, that your help is so much appreciated!!!!! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the return value of `BeginInvoke` method which is of type  `DispatcherOperation`.

For more info read:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcheroperation.aspx